# How to select a word from a set of 2 randomly and display it?

Tags: vb.net

***THIS IS A CONSOLE APPLICATION***

How do I display text randomly but that of which I have put into the program?

**Example:** I am making a heads or tails game. I want to make it so you input your choice (Heads/Tails), and it randomly says "Heads" or "Tails", and on the next line, it says "You win" or "You lose" based on the match.

I just don't know how to make it select text from the program at random and display it.

Comment: have a look at the `System.Random` class

Comment: @user1937198 Uh, what's that... I'm kinda new to this btw....

Comment: a class provided by the .net framework, a key part of vb.net. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Comment: @user1937198 Yea....... I kinda didn't understand that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
Dim prng As New Random
Dim done As Boolean = False

Sub Main()
    Do
        Dim toss As Integer = prng.Next(2) '0=heads, 1=tails
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine & "Enter (h)eads, (t)ails, or e(x)it")
        Dim inp As String = Console.ReadLine.ToLower
        Dim choice As Integer
        Select Case inp
            Case "h", "head", "heads"
                choice = 0
            Case "t", "tail", "tails"
                choice = 1
            Case "x", "exit"
                choice = -1
                done = True
            Case Else
                choice = 2 'input error
        End Select
        If choice = toss Then
            Console.WriteLine("Winner, winner, chicken dinner!")
        ElseIf choice = 2 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Input error, try again")
        ElseIf choice = -1 Then
            'exit
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("You lose")
        End If
    Loop While Not done
End Sub
```

Comment: :D Thanks! But mind explaining what Console.Writeline(Environment.NewLine & "Enter (h)eads, (t)ails, or e(x)it") does? I didn't get the Environment.NewLine part.

Comment: Try the online documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx